# Tracing touches in SegmentedControl for BlackBerry 10

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have a [`SegmentedControl`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__segmentedcontrol.html) on my [`Page`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__page.html) and I want to call methods on a C++ object when the selected value has changed. Each selectable [`Option`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__option.html) has its own method to call.

I need to know if the [`Option`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__option.html) was set by touch or by code, because if the method execution fails, I want to set the old value by code.

**Example:**

1. I set [`Option`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__option.html) B by touch

   1. [`Option`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__option.html) B's assigned method gets called
   2. the called method succeeds
2. I set [`Option`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__option.html) B by touch

   1. [`Option`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__option.html) B's assigned method gets called
   2. the called method failed
   3. [`Option`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__option.html) A is being set by code
   4. I don't want [`Option`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__option.html) A's assigned method to get called, because the [`Option`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__option.html) has been set by code

How can I detect if the [`Option`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__option.html) has been set by code or by touch?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can detect by touch or code. But you can make a workaround.

```
property bool byTouch: true
```

Let's go through your example

1. I set `Option` B by touch

   1. `Option` B's assigned method gets called
   2. the called method succeeds
2. I set `Option` B by touch

   1. `Option` B's assigned method gets called
   2. the called method failed
   3. `Option` A is being set by code, **I set `byTouch` to `false`**
   4. **I check if `byTouch` is true, and if it is, `Option` A's assigned method to get called**

You can obviously make the same `byTouch` check for `Option` B as well.